# NUnit Assert.That as extension

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

After working some time with FluentAssertions and returning back to NUnit I feel like it would be better to have instead of

```
 Assert.That(azimuth, Is.EqualTo(6.2234045).Within(1e-5));
```

something like

```
 azimuth.AssertThat(Is.EqualTo(6.2234045).Within(1e-5));
```

or even better

```
 azimuth.Is().EqualTo(6.2234045).Within(1e-5));
```

Not a big deal but in my opinion it has a little better readability. Especially when you have a lot of following fields.

Before I start writing extensions by myself, I thought, maybe there are some libraries or GitHUB project with it?

P.S. Unfortunately I can't use FluentAssertions for the project

Comment: Why would you *not* be able to use FluentAssertions?! But any other library would be fine... It's open source under apache license, so instead of rolling your own, you could take it and make it your own if you wanted.

Comment: That was a decision of my team. Main complain against FluentAssertions is that Resharper and NUnit test runners show wrong failure places in tests.

Comment: In that case NFluent may work... have you considered contacting the auhor about it?